# Can I use Date components in a variable name in swift and, if so, how?

Tags: swift, date, variable-declaration

I am using a struct to store records that include many optional fields, e.g.,

```
struct record {
    var age: Int?
    var ID: String?
    var firstName: String?
    var lastName: String?
}
```

Ideally I want to autodeclare a variable named by current date information each time a new record is created, e.g.,

```
var [Date()] = record()
```

or whatever would achieve the equivalent end result of...

```
var _03142022 = record()
```

I've been unable to locate any examples or relevant analogues and am not certain if I am trying to do something impossible/stupid, or am just failing to find the right search terms.

Comment: How about using a dictionary such as `[Date: record]` instead?

Comment: This is nit usual in swift but  [there](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/articles/55/how-to-use-dynamic-member-lookup-in-swift) you may find interesting ideas.

Comment: @Sweeper - Just to clarify (I'm new to dictionaries), is the idea that I declare a dictionary that will contain all records, and then each new record is added as a key-value pair to where 'creation date' is the 'key' and the record struct instance is the 'value'?  thanks